# Does Ubuntu 10.04 have a GUI app to manage folder and file permissions?

Tags: ubuntu, software-rec, permissions

Does Ubuntu 10.04 have a GUI app to manage folder and file permissions instead of using chmod manually in terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the file or folder and go to the Permissions tab. There you can set permissions for that file/folder.

Launching a file browser with su access:

```
gksu nautilus <DIRECTORY>
```

Comment: You're very welcome!

Comment: @meyosef: If you found this answer helpful, consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) by clicking the checkmark!